# Put custom rule in Cloudwatch events using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to trigger a lambda function based on rule added in cloudwatch event. I saw an example of doing it in console like this,

```
{
    "detail-type": [
        "Glue Crawler State Change"
    ],
    "source": [
        "aws.glue"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "crawlerName": [
            "MyTestCrawl"
        ],
        "state": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to add my lambda function as target. Is there a way to do it using boto3?

Comment: Would you like to run lambda with cron expression from rule? May be this would help, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#EventBridge.Client.put_targets

Answer (score -1):

Invoke your lambda function through boto3. See the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke)

Below is the example.

```
response = client.invoke(
    ClientContext='MyApp',
    FunctionName='MyFunction',
    InvocationType='Event',
    LogType='Tail',
    Payload='fileb://file-path/input.json',
    Qualifier='1',
)
```